# Can't get a computer with a unique mainboard to boot. The system plays a beeping sound on boot and we are not sure what it means?

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard

When we boot the computer nothing displays on the monitor and the mainboard plays a sound. The mainboard isn’t a standard computer main board. It is for an automatic car wash pump stand. But it has BIOS and CPU etc… like a standard computer.

I have tried cleaning connections spraying it with air gun and checked the BIOS battery voltage. Its 3.2V.

I have a short video of the beeping sound. Does anyone know it means? I’m assuming I need a new mainboard?

Here [is video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/-iEAG4V9SIo) of the computer of booting. Sound happens after a few seconds.

The mainboard is a IOWA-LX-600S. I think the manual for this MB is [this manual](https://dls.ieiworld.com/IEIWeb/Reserved/0B122392196172799113/IOWA-LX-600_UMN_v1.00.pdf).

The OS runs on compact flash memory card on the back of the mainboard.

I have pictures I took of the board while I was at work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's likely a POST beep code of some sort. It's not one I've heard before (and they're manufacturer and sometimes type specific), so you really need to check the main board manual. The board should have a type printed on it, try to search for that one online.

Comment: You won't necessarily need a new main board. It could also be a faulty video card, RAM or (rarer) CPU. The code should tell you where the self test fails.

Comment: Thanks @MiG I've had a look through a manual I found on an online search and the only instance of a 'beep' i saw was for a 'virus warning'. But a virus is impossible as this computer is not connected to the internet :)

Comment: It's not impossible, an infected USB drive (for example with MP3s) could still infect it. But ignore that reference, that's only if you have enabled this function (and it just says 'beeps', does not describe the sound pattern).

Comment: The only reference I can find that *could* match this pattern is about memory issues, it's not really sourced though. I don't see a DIMM to remove/reseat however, did you remove it or is it embedded (i.e. those four chips at the top)? Note that you should handle main board and memory while grounded (for example a grounded antistatic wristband) or you might introduce more problems.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Comment: Good info added. Looking at the pics this seems ancient and proprietary. My best guess is that blue CMOS battery is dead. The battery itself is a fairly standard CR2302 battery but has those wires. My advice? Get a new battery. Doing a search online for “[CR2032 with wires](https://www.google.com/search?q=CR2032+with+wires)” shows lots of options including “[CR2032 with molex connector](https://www.google.com/search?q=cr2032+with+molex+connector).” My interpretation of the numbers (15 6 11) on that CR2032 means it was made on June 15, 2011. Worth assuming the battery is dead. Get a new one.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll have a play around with it. I definently did not remove a DIMM or anything from the board so must be embedded. My concern is the board have have corroded over time as we use alkaline on our automatic systems.  I'll try a new battery als. Thanks. And if i get actually get it to boot Ill post on here the solution